# Laravel passport unsupported_grant_type with client credentials

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-9, laravel-passport

I'm trying to do machine-to-machine authentication for an api I'm building (no user involved). I've followed the limited documentation for Laravel Passport surrounding the client credentials option, but I keep getting `unsupported_grant_type`.

My Api route:

```php
Route::post('/oauth/token', [AccessTokenController::class, 'issueToken'])->middleware(['throttle']);
```

I can see through ngrok that the request is going through, so I feel like it's configured correctly. I've also added a test endpoint which works fine.

```php
Route::get('/test', fn () => response()->json(['message' => 'Welcome to the API!']));
```

My config in auth.config:

```php
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

int `config/passport.php` I set the guard to api:

```php
'guard' => 'api',
```

I've got Content-Type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and Accept headers set to `application/json`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[image: postman request and response]

**UPDATE:**

For anyone who stumbles across this, apparently I was missing the `Content-Length` header, which I didn't realize was required, but is. I just happened to try it and it solved my problem. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I ran into this problem AGAIN, and stumbled upon my previous question which helped me solve it, I figured I'd go ahead and post the solution to the problem so when I google it again next time I run into this problem it'll be here.

The `Content-Length` header is required. If you don't have it, you'll get an Unsupported Grant Type error message, which will leave you stumped and googling.

You're welcome, future self.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but may be one of these steps would help you:

- `php artisan passport:install`
- Make sure that when you created the client, you used the --client option which indicates a client credentials grant client:
  `php artisan passport:client --client`
- app/Http/Kernel.php

```
'web' => [
    // ... other middleware ...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

- In `config/app.php`, make sure the `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class` service provider is registered.
- In the register method of `AuthServiceProvider`, make sure you have:
  `Passport::routes();`
- Finally, run `php artisan config:clear`